# How to install a program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, administrator, right-click, double-click

Is it Right Click > Run As Administrator
or
Double Click?

I had to uninstall and reinstall some programs many times to get it to work and I'm not sure it is because I chose one or the other.

Historically, for Windows XP, you should Start > Run. For Windows 8, you should double click.

Comment: Most programs don't require Administrator access to be install.  Why do you want to run installations with Administrator permissions?  The process of installing a program is exactly the same on any supported version of Windows.

Comment: Seriously, this is a valid question. Why all the downvotes? I have done extensive Google search before asking this question

Comment: You don't really explain the reason you believe installing a program in Windows 7 is any different than installing a program on Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: your title says Windows 7 and in your post you mention windows 8 and windows XP. That's three different versions of Windows. On top of that, there's also Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, but I assume that you use Windows 8.1 (and not 8).

Couple of things:

- All three versions allow you to run almost every program as administrator by right-clicking the link.
- If you double-click something ("the normal way"), you run it as the user you're currently logged in with. This is good enough for almost everything.
- All three versions allow you to do the Start -> Run thing, though Windows 7 and 8 don't call it "Start" any more. The easiest way to access that Run thingy is to press the Windows key on your keyboard together with the 'r' key (r as in "run").

Running as administrator should only be necessary in "special cases", e.g. running a command prompt or some system configuration program in administrator mode to be able to issue some potentially dangerous system commands, or a sysadmin installing an application on a computer where a limited user is logged on (often the case in corporate networks).

So, the short answer is: just double click. If that doesn't work correctly and you don't know why, but it does work when you run it as administrator, you're probably doing something you shouldn't be doing, or your user accounts are misconfigured. In such cases, please ask a more specific/detailed question here and you have a much better chance to get some useful case-specific information.

Good luck!

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen

Comment: Thanks. By the way, one more thing: starting an application through start->run (or windowskey+r) is almost always the same as starting that same application by doubleclicking a shortcut on your desktop or the start menu. (This *can* be modified by hardcoding a shortcut to start its target in "run as administrator" mode, but normally isn't.) There are also ways to run something as administrator in the start->run thingy, by prefixing your command with certain command modifiers, but normally that also does "the normal way" (i.e. running as the currently logged in user, i.e. not as admin).